# Pyinstaller creating exe file without pandas but still requires pandas import

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, pyinstaller

I have a python code which runs fine when I run it through the cmd using python filename.py

But when I create exe file using pyinstaller the exe file opens and prints an exception I made(see at the bottom of the code) says no module name pandas.

Then, If I edit the code and import pandas and recreate the exe file it will work.

Does anyone have an idea?

I'm not using pandas in the code, and even PyCharm marks the import pandas line as redundant.
I have Windows 10 and anaconda installed.

Thank you

```
import csv,re

import os.path, time, datetime

import subprocess

import sys

try:

    nameOfTitle= "name"
    SName="S"
    os.chdir(r'someaddress')
    summaries_csv_path="summaries.csv"
    HtmlPath='html/-----.htm'
    HtmlPathNoDir='-----.htm'
    HtmlPathNoDirC='----.htm'
    HtmlPathNoDir='-----.htm'

    sub="name"
    headerH3="------"
    dataWlCsv="raw.zip"
    opRow = 0
    sumRow = 0
    col_num=0
    innerCount=0
    x = 0
    headerList = list()
    htmlfile = open(HtmlPath,"w")

    execfile(r'some address')#header

    readOp = csv.reader(open(r'some address.csv'),delimiter=',')

    for row in readOp: # Read a single row from the CSV file
        execfile(r'\some address.py')#logic

    execfile(r'some address.py')#footer


except:
   e = sys.exc_info()[1]

   print("<p>Error: %s</p>" % e)
   print "IN "+" MODUL!"
```